# call a Stored Procedure from Hibernate having multiple ref cursor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

I am trying to retrieve values from the Stored Procedure. This stored procedure has two ref cursors. Below is the SP:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "EMP_JOB" (
    p_job           VARCHAR2,
    p_emp_refcur    IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    p_sal_refcur    IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_emp_refcur FOR 
    SELECT empno, ename 
    FROM emp 
    WHERE job = p_job;

    OPEN p_sal_refcur FOR 
    SELECT sal 
    FROM emp 
    WHERE job = p_job;
END;
```

Here is my java code:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("EMP_JOB")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2,  Class.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(3,  Class.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)        
                .setParameter(1, "CLERK");

query.execute();
Iterator queryIterator = query.getResultList().iterator();
ArrayList<Object> vinArray= new ArrayList<Object>();

while(queryIterator.hasNext()){
     Object st= (Object)queryIterator.next();
     vinArray.add(st);
}
```

I can retrieve the output for the parameter 2( `p_emp_refcur IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR`).

How can I get the get the output for parameter 3( `p_sal_refcur IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR`).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue already raised to Hibernate team:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12596

Comment: It's 2020 and this is still isn't fixed. One would be well advised in avoiding using Hibernate's JPA support.

Answer (score 2):

Seems it's still not possible. But, Here is a workaround by getting connection from Hibernate `EntityManager` and then using `CallableStatement`.

---

```java
// Session = org.hibernate.Session
// entityManager = javax.persistence.EntityManager

Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.doWork(new Work() {

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        // do something useful
        try (CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{CALL TEST_PACKAGE.GETCURSORS(?,?,?)}")) {
            cs.setInt(1, 1);
            cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            cs.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            cs.execute();
            ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(2);
            ResultSet rs1 = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(3);
            while (rs.next()) {
                int a = rs.getInt(1);
                System.out.println(a);
            }
            while (rs1.next()) {
                int b = rs1.getInt(1);
                System.out.println(b);
            }
        }
    }
});
```